# Devise sends confirmation instructions for the first user only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sidekiq

I'm trying to migrate sending mails from Sidekiq's Delayed Extensions (as it's deprecated) to ActionMailer and it's `deliver_later` functionality. All mailers have been migrated successfully, except the Devise's one.

Previously I've used `devise-async` gem with the following method in my `User` model:

```rb
def deliver_mail_later(notification, model, args)
  devise_mailer.delay.send(notification, model, *args)
end
```

I've decided to remove `devise-async` gem as it's possible to handle it by overriding `send_devise_notification` method (as it's suggested in Devise's docs). As a result, I have the following method in my `User` model currently:

```rb
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```

ActiveJob is required in my `application.rb` file and I've configured Sidekiq as it's queue adapter:

```rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

I have been using Sidekiq's workers in this project for a few years, so the Sidekiq's configuration is most likely correct (as workers are working as expected).

Unfortunatelly, such a configuration works for the first user after application server restart only. When the first user signs up, everything works as expected. For the next users, the confirmation mail is not being sent. Restarting application server helps for one another user, but after that it breaks once again.

There is a log generated for the failed user. It looks like some kind of the race condition to me.

```bash
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [49b45404-5fdc-422b-bc71-f489d0ae94ea] Error performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: 49b45404-5fdc-422b-bc71-f489d0ae94ea) from Async(mailer) in 4.91ms: ActiveJob::DeserializationError (Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find User with 'id'=22):
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:381:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:475:in `find_one'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:457:in `find_with_ids'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:69:in `find'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:22:in `find'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/core.rb:271:in `find'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/globalid-1.1.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:129:in `locate'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/globalid-1.1.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:154:in `block in locate'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/globalid-1.1.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:164:in `block in unscoped'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:881:in `_scoping'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:428:in `scoping'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb:43:in `unscoped'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/globalid-1.1.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:164:in `unscoped'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/globalid-1.1.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:154:in `locate'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/globalid-1.1.0/lib/global_id/locator.rb:16:in `locate'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:148:in `deserialize_global_id'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:132:in `deserialize_argument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:129:in `block in deserialize_argument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:129:in `map'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:129:in `deserialize_argument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:162:in `block in deserialize_hash'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:162:in `transform_values'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:162:in `deserialize_hash'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:136:in `deserialize_argument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:43:in `block in deserialize'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:43:in `map'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:43:in `deserialize'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/core.rb:190:in `deserialize_arguments'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/core.rb:180:in `deserialize_arguments_if_needed'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:44:in `perform_now'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `block in perform_now'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:25:in `block in instrument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:35:in `instrument'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `perform_now'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `block in perform_now'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:25:in `tag_logger'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `perform_now'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sentry-rails-5.8.0/lib/sentry/rails/active_job.rb:9:in `block in perform_now'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sentry-rails-5.8.0/lib/sentry/rails/active_job.rb:35:in `block in record'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sentry-ruby-5.8.0/lib/sentry/hub.rb:59:in `with_scope'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sentry-ruby-5.8.0/lib/sentry-ruby.rb:355:in `with_scope'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sentry-rails-5.8.0/lib/sentry/rails/active_job.rb:23:in `record'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sentry-rails-5.8.0/lib/sentry/rails/active_job.rb:8:in `perform_now'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:24:in `block in execute'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:54:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `block in wrap'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:71:in `wrap'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.4.3/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb:70:in `perform'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
/home/tomasz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
User excluded error: #<ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find User with 'id'=22>
```

I've tried to use built-in configuration for Devise mailers (without custom `send_devise_notification` method), but it sends mail synchronously then - that's unacceptable in my case.

Using `devise-async` functionality has the same issue - only first user is handled properly:

```rb
def deliver_mail_later(notification, model, args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, model, *args).deliver_later
end
```

Comment: It's not a race condition, it's this: Couldn't find User with 'id'=22):

Comment: Please post the controller or model code that calls the this mailer.

Comment: `Async(mailer)` not sidekiq. my guess is that you call `send_devise_notification` inside of a transaction. which would work with slow poke sidekiq, but async is faster. first one works because code is still loading, so there is more time for transaction to commit.